# Reading and writing to files

Tags: c#

I have a few questions. Yes this is homework and I am just trying to understand it.

This is what is being asked.

> • When the button “Load” is clicked, read the file specified in the textbox (txtFilePath: Absolute path not relative) and add the objects found within to the listbox
>
> • When the user clicks the “Save” button, write the selected record to the file specified in txtFilePath (absolute path not relative) without truncating the values currently inside

Can someone please explain to me as I am still learning this. I have the button and the textbox there and the same with the save. Now with the save button will I just have the same code as you would if you just wanted to save it. But from what I am gathering there is a database so you can load the file that you saved. Or am I making this harder than what it is?

Comment: Look at System.IO.File for easy methods to read/append to a file.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding this? listbox values come from file, select an item in list-box, then write that selected item back to the file without removing other entries (isn't it already in that file given it just populated the listbox?) Or is the professor assuming txtFilePath will change between read/save access?

Comment: @Brad I have no clue what he wants with the txtFilePath. I think that is why I am more confused because I know I can load and save it without using it.

Comment: @shan: Chances are your prof. wants the ability to use a file on his/her system instead of a "perfect" file you would supply. This proves you can read and write to any generic file. However, saving back an entry to a file where the list originated from, to me, seems odd. -- p.s. if you're not already, I'd use [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) to populate txtFilePath ;-)

Comment: That you Brad, yes I understand now I have to use the openFileDialog in here.

Comment: @shan: If you get stuck [check this out](http://pastebin.com/hzXypzpm). But I'd still ask why you're saving back a value that inevitably came from that same file. Also, are you supposed to confirm it isn't already an entry in the file before saving it back, or just append it as many times as the user clicks save?

Comment: @Brad I just got informed that I do not need to use the OpenFile Dialog.

Comment: @Shan: not even for extra credit? :p

Comment: No and thats the thing is I only learned how to do it with openFile Dialog so now that even makes me more confused I am trying to find things on the internet that will help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no database.  In these instructions, `record` == `some selected item` that needs to be *appended* to an existing file.  Just use a stream and a writer to save the file to disk and you satisfy the requirement.

Comment: *Selected* record.  `record` != `file`, `record` = `SelectedItem` (?) it sounds like to me.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no database. What you do is interact with the Windows file system (eg, the files on your hard drive). You use the classes in the `System.IO` namespace to load and save files.

'Absolute path' refers to the unique location of a file in the drive expressed as a rooted expression; a 'relative path' is a partial path that points to a file relative to a given location:

```
c:\foo\bar\baz\my files\homework.txt
..\..\homework.txt
```

Those are an absolute and relative paths.

I'm not sure how much detail you are looking for here, it's hard to give a complete overview of the way filesystems work. You might want to look at the basic examples in MSDN that deal with file management.

Answer (score 1):

First of all read up on how to read and write files. Here's a good link I found:

[check it out](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx)

Next what you'll want to do is put your read/write code in the Button_Click event of each button (double click on your buttons to auto create this event assuming your using Visual Studio)

You can easily retrieve the path from your text box by accessing the .text() property of your textbox

```
string path = myTextBox.Text;
```

It's been a while since I've coded anything in c# but this is pretty basic and I think it should help.

Comment: @shan If your have a "record" there is a database or at least a dataset of an array or some kind of collection. Once selecting the record you can write it to a file by doing what I posted above.

Comment: Properties don't have () in C#. it's just `myTextBox.Text`

Comment: @jb. +1 for the good spot. Sorry as I said it's been awhile since I've done anything in c#. Answer edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a detailed analysis of this subject as it is quite a wide topic.

For file interaction you must use the System.IO namespace which has classes to easily load and save files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx

The link above is a good reference on MSDN on how you can get started with File Management using System.IO.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your question is wether or not you need to read the file a second time before saving or otherwise treat if differently than if you created a new file.

I would say "no". You have already read the content of the file into the listbox. You just need to get the edited content from the listbox (when the user is done with it) and save it to the file (overwriting whatever is there).

Comment: "without truncating the values currently inside" ie do not overwrite the save file, append to it.

Answer (score 1):

**For Load:**

1. [Read the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94223t4d.aspx) line by line
2. [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx) each line to the ListBox Items

**For Save:**

1. [Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663.aspx) your save file without truncating (ie append to the file)
2. [For each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) item in your ListBox Items, write it to the save file